# dynamically populating variable with loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am dynamically generating json data as below

```
 <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
        len = "<%- gsdata.length %>"


    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //window.alert(len);
        var data = {

        "Results": [{
            "SCRIP": gsdata[i].SCRIP,
            "LTP": gsdata[i].LTP,
            "ALERT": gsdata[i].CAMARILLA,
            "TRIGERP": gsdata[i].ALERT,
            "BOOKAT": gsdata[i].BOOKAT,
            "PROFIT": gsdata[i].PROFIT,
        }]

        }
    }

        $('#scrip-data').DataTable({

        data: data.Results,
            columns: [

                {data: "SCRIP"},
                {data: "LTP"},
                {data: "ALERT"},
                {data: "TRIGERP"},
                {data: "BOOKAT"},
                {data: "PROFIT"},
            ],

        });
    } );
    </script>
```

This is an ejs template and loop is inside `<script>` tags. I am not able to get the value of `i` in the `"SCRIP": "<%- gsdata[i].XXX %>". with "SCRIP": "<%- gsdata[1].SCRIP %>"` I am able to get the values.

Any help here please

Comment: shouldn't your for loop be in ejs syntax?

Comment: Why are you looping over the length of the JSON string, not the `gsdata` array itself?

Comment: Yes that was a typo, len = "<%- gsdata.length %>" and used the variable to loop through.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (i don't kow ejs), but i would think that you need to indicate that the for loop is part of the template, and not part of the script tag "output" :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  len = "<%- gsdata.length %>"

   //window.alert(len);
    var data = {

      "Results": [ 
         <%- for (var i = 0; i < gsdata.length; i++) { %>
         {
          "SCRIP": "<%- gsdata[i].SCRIP %>",
          "LTP": "<%- gsdata[i].LTP %>",
          "ALERT": "<%- gsdata[i].CAMARILLA %>",
          "TRIGERP": "<%- gsdata[i].ALERT %>",
          "BOOKAT": "<%- gsdata[i].BOOKAT %>",
          "PROFIT": "<%- gsdata[i].PROFIT %>",
        },
        <%- } %>
    ]
  }
</script>
```

Updated to what I think poster is looking for... guessing though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use EJS syntax inside JavaScript.

And you shouldn't call `JSON.stringify()` to get the length of the array. That returns the length of the serialized array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var len = gsdata.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    //window.alert(len);
    var data = {

      "Results": [{
        "SCRIP": gsdata[i].SCRIP,
        "LTP": gsdata[i].LTP,
        "ALERT": gsdata[i].CAMARILLA,
        "TRIGERP": gsdata[i].ALERT,
        "BOOKAT": gsdata[i].BOOKAT,
        "PROFIT": gsdata[i].PROFIT,
      }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: OR Results = []; and in loop Results.push(...)

Comment: That's a separate problem. This is obviously only part of the code, since it never uses `data`.

Comment: your solution looks like it will create n data variables; each one hoisted and therefore the one remaining in scope will be the nth element of gsdata.  Agreed it is not what the poster is asking - but also not sure the poster understands exactly what to ask (yet).

Comment: @Barmar I have updated the entire code. After using your solution now my dataTable is empty . In the logs I see gsdata as undefined